# Editing Build Description in Jenkins through Java

Tags: java, post, jenkins

I'm trying to edit job description in Jenkins. Previously I did it through bash doing 'curl --data-urlencode 'description=ABCDEFGH' --data-urlencode "Submit=Submit" "https://Login/APItoken@jenkinsURL/job/JobName/Build/submitDescription". Now, I would like to do the same but through Java. This is what I have so far. As always, "it should work but it doesn't" in my opinion:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;


public class JenkinsDesUpdate {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        URL url = new URL("https://Login:APItoken@jenkinsURL/job/JobName/Build/configSubmit");


         Map <String,Object> params = new LinkedHashMap<>();
            params.put("description", "THIS IS A NEW DESCRIPTION");
            params.put(DisplayName","THIS IS A NEW DISPLAY NAME");
            StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();

            for (Map.Entry <String,Object> param : params.entrySet()) {
                if (postData.length() != 0) postData.append('&');
                postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
                postData.append('=');
                postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param.getValue()), "UTF-8")); 
            }


            byte[] postDataBytes = postData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postDataBytes.length));
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);

            Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

            for (int c; (c = in.read()) >= 0;)
                System.out.print((char)c);

    }

}
```

Ok, let me hear your thoughts. What I get is the HTML of a site with:

```
function showTranslationDialog() {
  if(!translation.launchDialog)
    loadScript("address/plugin/translation/dialog.js");
  else
    translation.launchDialog();
  return false; 
}</script></body></html>
```

if my URL is ".../Build" or

server returned HTTP response code: 403

when my URL's ".../Build/configSubmit" as above in the code.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use jenkins client sdk's to get interacted.

Java - https://github.com/jenkinsci/java-client-api

Python - https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jenkinsapi